Identify this movie about ghost bar/casino
I have tried to identify this movie since a long time.
It seems like a 90's movies but I'm not sure. It's about different ghost like creatures, who come to a bar/casino where they play cards and other games with other witches, halfdead, etc. During one such game, a player cuts all the fingers of the other player (both of the players are ugly looking half dead).
Its a horror comedy and I watched it on TV approximately 8 years ago on HBO India.

The closest i could find so far is this movie http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0864331/ but the time frame blows it out for the range, not sure if it's the one you seek

@Morpheus no its not because your mentioned movie is horror but i am talking about comedy horror.

With the reference of Juanze's answer I got what I am searching for. It's Bordello of Blood (also known as Tales from the Crypt Presents: Bordello of Blood). The scene I am taking about is 

The Cryptkeeper is having lunch with the Mummy (William Sadler), who
  is boring the Cryptkeeper about his life in the film industry. The
  Mummy challenges the Crypt Keeper to a contest of rock, paper,
  scissors which the Mummy wins, and he slices off the Keeper's hand
  with a meat cleaver. The Cryptkeeper laughs (as it didn't hurt him at
  all) and the Mummy gets ready for the next round. The Cryptkeeper
  addresses the audience, and the movie continues.

And the game I am talking about is Rock–paper–scissors.

Could be "Cutting Cards", from "Tales from the Crypt" series?

I think you deserve the bounty because your answer helped me a lot.
